# Is There a Limit to Timelord “Bigger on the Inside” Technology?

Tags: doctor-who, tardis

In a previous question about the [side of the TARDIS interior](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7608/how-big-is-the-interior-of-the-tardis) no actual answer to the size of the interior of the TARDIS could be found.  And at the [Battle of Canary Wharf](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Battle_of_Canary_Wharf) we see the [Genesis Ark](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Genesis_Ark) as what looks like at least several thousand Daleks emerge from it, even though it doesn't look big enough to hold more than one Dalek.

I know we can't answer this question on our own, but there's decades of *Doctor Who* canon, so I'm wondering if someone may have heard something about this somewhere along the line.

Is there a limit, in Timelord technology, to how large an interior of a container can be compared to the exterior size of the container?  If there isn't an absolute limit, is there any kind of practical limit, such as how much power it takes to create the larger interior or to maintain the connection between the interior and the exterior?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The interior of the Tardis is a pocket universe which may require energy to initially to create.

However, in "Rise of the Cybermen", the Tardis (almost) completely loses power. Implying that there is no energy requirement to sustain the pocket universe, or to keep the exterior door of the Tardis bound to the pocket universe.

There has never been a mention of a limit to the interior size, and I think the implication has been that there is none.

However, there may be a maximum size after which the Tardis won't be able to function properly: In "Castrovalva", the Doctor 'jettisons' or 'deletes' 25% of the Tardis's internal structure to provide additional thrust. The implication is that the power required to move the Tardis is tied to the total mass of the interior.

Comment: "The Doctor's Wife" also showed the Doctor removing rooms from the TARDIS interior to increase power. Why this should be the case is a mystery, but I think it's similar to the way a computer sometimes needs to free up blocks of memory in order to carry out an intensive computation.

Comment: During *Journey to the centre of the TARDIS*, the Doctor told "This ship is infinite". I don't know if he exaggerated it or if he really meant it.

Comment: @TrevörAnneDenise: Yeah but that episode also re-introduced the Eye Of Harmony as being inside the ship, whereas _Rise of the Cybermen_ shows that the TARDIS doesn't draw its power from any internal source. So it's all a mess.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Even the fact that the TARDIS can loose all its power due to quite simple external events (such as in Flatline) is surprising in my opinion since it's powered by a star...

Comment: @TrevörAnneDenise: Yeah that too :(

Comment: On the deleting rooms part, matter and energy are interchangeable according to the theory of relativity. I always took the 'deleting rooms' thing to mean converting the matter to energy (for more power) rather than trying to reduce mass. The time lords may be able to convert mass to energy with near 100% efficiency. I got the impression that the tardis creates rooms (mass) from energy (stores the energy as matter) then converts them back to energy when needed, acting as an insanely powerful capacitor

Answer (score 2):

The Doctor also jettisons Romana's room in Logopolis to generate more thrust.

Late 70s, early 80s era stories such as the Invasion of Time (where the Tardis is massive), Logopolis (where Tegan gets lost) suggest that the interior is very very large - making it a bit irrational of the Doctor to home in on Romana's room.  Maybe he wanted to jettison the memories as well.  I think these stories influenced Neil Gaiman as well in the Doctors Wife where Amy and Rory are running through the Tardis.

In the Doctors Wife it is also suggested that the Tardis keeps an archive of the old control rooms (what a sentimental old thing)  Suggesting that some process can add/remove rooms under a control.  Perhaps this is a use of Block Transfer Computations alluded to in Logopolis, Castrovalva and the extended media.  The Tardis can "store" energy by converting it to rooms like a battery charging only to delete them later and get the energy back

On the other hand in "the impossible planet", the Doctor says that Tardises are grown and then a carving process begins.  However if they were carved in the way that we understand it, then concepts such as the Tardis "Desktop theme" wont really apply.  Also as we see in the eleventh hour, the Tardis can regenerate herself, suggesting a fluidity where rooms can be added or removed and not a fixed carved structure.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's never been a practical limit given, and the space is theoretically infinite.  I would assume that once you've created a gateway to an extra-spatial dimension which has malleable dimensions and reconfigurable geometry there's no real difference between the space being 1 cubic foot or big enough to contain planets.