# If the TARDIS is infinite, doesn’t that mean it contains everything?

Tags: doctor-who, tardis

If the TARDIS is infinite, then wouldn't that mean that it contains every single possible outcome of any event in ALL of space and time? Including an infinite amount of planets, solar systems, Daleks, Cybermen, TARDISes, exploding TARDISes, black holes, wormholes, other Time Lords, other Doctors and entire universes, all inside itself?

Comment: To the close-voters: this may be based on a false premise, but it's still clear what the question is. It's not "unclear what the OP is asking".

Comment: Related: [How big is the interior of the TARDIS?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7608/how-big-is-the-interior-of-the-tardis)

Comment: The set of even numbers is infinite, but it doesn't contain every number.

Comment: I think you could think about it like the paradox of the [Hilbert hotel](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_paradox_of_the_Grand_Hotel) - on this page they also discuss the "cigar mystery" - which might be the answer for you.

Comment: From 0 to infinity is infinite, but does not contain -1.

Comment: Even though the Tardis's dimensions are infinite that doesn't mean it contains a particular thing.  It could all be empty space and still be "infinite".

Comment: You don't have to get that fancy.  The fraction 1/3 is 0.3333... An infinite number of 3's.  There's no saying it can't just repeat the same thing over and over infinitely.  (Unlike, say, an irrational number, which is both infinite *and* non-repeating.)

Comment: A half-plane is infinite, but doesn't contain the whole plane. Even though your question is vague, I can still point out that "infinite" doesn't mean "universal". Just because something is big, there's no reason there couldn't be something even bigger.

Comment: FYI the main source of the idea that a "large to infinite" universe contains everything possible is Max Tegmark. see http://space.mit.edu/home/tegmark/crazy.html for more info

Comment: It's only infinite *on the inside*.

Comment: Don't forget that the inside of the TARDIS is "basically another dimension."  You can fit a lot of stuff (and infinite amount, actually) in another dimension and have none of it appear in the "normal" dimensions we live in.

Answer (score 58):

The TARDIS is described as infinite in size in 'Journey to the Centre of the TARDIS', but it should be remembered that 'the Doctor lies', so it may in fact not be infinite at all.

However, if we take the statement to be true, and the TARDIS is indeed infinite in size, it helps to realise that 'infinite' does not necessarily mean 'everything'.

For example:

- The set of all real numbers is infinte.

  The set of all whole numbers is also infinite, yet it clearly does not contain all real numbers, so it is a different infinite set (and indeed smaller, in the sense of lower cardinality).
- Similarly, there is an infinite number of fractions between 0 and 1, yet it clearly doesn't include any number over 1 or less than 0, so it is another example of a different infinite set.

The TARDIS may well be infinite in size, but that doesn't mean it contains everything.

Comment: It still drives me crazy that there are different sizes of infinity. My brain just sort of sits down and gives up whenever I think about that.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite I think the [diagonal argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor's_diagonal_argument) is quite easy to follow.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite It gets much worse: Take care not to read about cardinal numbers - they make things like countable and uncoutable infinity look harmless: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_number

Comment: @PaulD.Waite: You're in good company.  When Georg Cantor discovered the infinite Cantor Set, it *literally* drove him nuts pondering the ramifications of it.

Comment: @LoopSpace Maybe your edit was a bit too drastic (hence why it was rejected). Remember the OP isn't asking for a lecture on set theory :-) I suggest you make another edit which simply removes the statements about "'smaller' infinite sets", with maybe a short paragraph at the end about the different 'sizes of infinity'. Alternatively (or additionally), why not post your own answer going into the Cantorian theory of ordinals, cardinals, and infinities in more detail? I would sure as hell upvote that (provided it also answered the question, of course).

Comment: @Randal'Thor I sort of figured that tojo's comment gave me permission to fix it _properly_.  The edit I've just made is what I consider to be the minimal changes to make it mathematically make sense.

Comment: @LoopSpace I can see your point, and if tojo had been around when you submitted your previous edit, it probably would've been approved. Unfortunately people don't normally check the comments on a post before approving edits on it. Anyway I just approved your new edit - and once again encourage you to post your own answer presenting a more advanced mathematical viewpoint to the issue than any of the answers so far :-)

Comment: But the set of whole numbers *is* smaller than the set of real numbers, in both in the sense of lower cardinality and the fact that the first is a subset of the second.

Comment: @Jonah Yes, but the set of rationals in [0,1] isn't smaller than the set of all rationals (or integers) in the first of those senses.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite The mathematician Kronecker has a solution for you: assume that the transfinite sets that have higher cardinality than the integers don't have any "real" existence in a Platonic sense. He famously quipped "God made the integers; all else is the work of man." The continuum (i.e. the "real" number line) can therefore be thought of as simply a man-made construct with no bearing on philosophical reality. (This is actually something like what I believe, even though I am fairly certain that I do in fact understand the basics of Cantor's math.)

Comment: @PaulD.Waite But we can make this kind of argument without requiring different infinities. For example, consider the even integers versus all of the integers. Both of these sets are infinite. While every even integer is an integer, not every integer is even, in fact, both of these sets have exactly the same size.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: they’re the same size? The even-integers-versus-all-integers example was the one I first heard to explain *differently*-sized infinities.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Whoever explained it to you was mistaken. :-( They're the same size because you can pair every integer with an even integer: pair n with 2n. So, in the same way that being able to pair every left sock with a right sock means you have the same number of left and right socks, there are the same number of integers and even integers (even though, in this case, some "socks" are both left and right). To get different sized infinities, you need to look at, e.g., the integers and the real numbers; Cantor's diagonal argument shows that there are many, many more reals than integers.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite DavidRicherby is exactly right; infinite proper subsets can still be the same size as the containing set(s). This sounds confusing, but when you start attempting this one-to-one pairing of elements between sets, it does start to make sense, and you see why the "proper subset" relationship is inadequate for comparing the size of infinite sets. And the diagonalization proof is the first place you should go to try to understand truly different sizes of infinity; it's brilliantly simple (even without a deep background in mathematics) and is the basis for many more interesting results.

Answer (score 24):

No. Being infinitely spacious in no way means it contains all possible universes. It just means the TARDIS is physically infinite, in that it goes on forever. Nothing about "everything that can happen, does happen" or whatnot, just infinite rooms and space to put things like a pool, a library, etc.

> 11TH DOCTOR: Picture the biggest ship you’ve ever seen. Are you picturing it?
>
> BRAM: Yeah.
>
> 11TH DOCTOR: Good. Now forget it. Because this ship is infinite.
> <sub>- *Journey to the Center of the TARDIS*</sub>

Comment: I hated this quote. :( I really hope we can canonically say he was being hyperbolic.

Comment: Rule #1: The Doctor lies. Specially the 11th.

Comment: TARDISes are grown, not built. So if they would really have to grow to infinite size, it would take an infinite time for one to be finished.

Comment: Simplest explanation for why the answer is a flat "no".

Comment: @MrLister I don't think that's necessarily true. My assumption has always been that the space inside the TARDIS folds in upon itself in such a way that the "infinite space" is simply how 3-dimensional beings are forced to perceive it, like some kind of transdimensional annulus. This requires nothing so silly as "the inside of this box extends in all three physical dimensions forever and ever, and got that way by growing at a finite speed." Alternatively, one could assume that the inside of the TARDIS is finite at any given point in time, but will automatically extend itself as it is explored.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit What do you hate about this quote?

Comment: @MrLister And if they were built, instead of grown... that would be different how exactly? :D Whatever builds/grows the infinity in TARDIS, it isn't building it atom by atom.

Comment: @KyleStrand: It's hard to put into words. The TARDIS is transcendetally massive, fine. "Infinite"? Doesn't seem to fit into anything we've seen or heard before about that ship. It just seemed like unnecessary hyperbole. Perhaps I could be clearer once I've thought about it more.

Comment: @Luaan If a TARDIS were built, if would be built by Time Lords using Gallifreyan technology. I'm sure they wouldn't need an infinite amount of time to build something infinite!

Comment: @MrLister Exactly. So what prevents them from designing a life-form that uses the same kind of technology? :P There's nothing *fundamentally* different between a life-form and a (sufficiently advanced) machine - TARDIS in particular seems to be rather tough compared to Earthly life, and would be easily capable of accommodating any kind of technology.

Comment: @Luaan TARDIS coral doesn't work like that.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit If not infinite, in what sense can its size be "transcendental"? Or were you just using that as an intensifier?

Comment: @KyleStrand: Transcendence isn't infiniteness. The term is specifically used in the show to describe how the TARDIS's dimensions escape the reality of the ship's external surroundings. http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Dimensional_transcendentalism

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Fair enough.

Answer (score 13):

No. Infinity is not Everything.

Think of it like this: There are infinitely many even numbers, yet not all numbers are even.

Comment: While correct, does this add anything to [the existing answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/124489/31394) by tojo?

Comment: @Randal'Thor: One could argue that more people are familiar with concepts like odd/even numbers than are with the set of whole/real numbers...but they could stand be merged.

Comment: This answer is correct, which tojo's isn't exactly.

Answer (score 11):

### Not necessarily

### An infinite set does not necessarily contain everything.

Consider the set of all [Fibonnaci numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number). This is an infinite set. Now, where in this set can you find the Daleks? I just looked at a lot of Fibonnaci numbers, and I didn't see any Daleks. If the Fibonnaci numbers don't contain the Daleks, why would you expect the TARDIS to do so?

### Some infinite sets are "smaller" than others

The set of all integers {...,-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, ...} has a certain cardinality. The set of real numbers has a different cardinality. This can be thought of in terms of whether there exists an bijection between the two sets. In addition, one set may nonetheless contain another set of the same cardinality, but different elements. For example, the integers contain the natural numbers. But the integers contain elements not seen in natural numbers {0, 1, 2, 3, ...}, for example, the number -1.

### Physics will not save you.

Many people would argue that under conventional physics anything macroscopic can form in a sufficiently large volume of matter, as in quantum mechanics most transitions are not truly forbidden but merely vanishingly improbable. It would follow that in an infinite volume of matter, there will be some subvolume that will form virtually anything you care to mention within a negligible time.

**The TARDIS does not run on conventional physics. Everything you know is wrong. Black is white up is down and short is long.**

If the TARDIS wants to have infinitely many corridors with no chance of transitioning to a Dalek, it can.

If the TARDIS wants to have infinite expanses of empty space that will never undergo a vacuum oscillation, **it can**.

But on the other hand, there's nothing stopping Moffat from endorsing exactly what you said, either.

Comment: “Black is white up is down and short is long” — left is banana, slow is heartfelt regret.

Comment: +1 because now I'll listen to that Weird Al Jankovic song in my brain all day. No, wait...-1

Comment: +1 for bringing in physics. Simplicio: "Sure, in math we can different infinities, but surely an infinite amount of *space* must eventually overlap with all other space in the known univers?" Salviati: "Physics will not save save you...The TARDIS does not run on conventional physics." Sagredo: "Ah, now I see."

Comment: First paragraph: Average Doctor Who fan. Second paragraph: Mathematician. Third paragraph: Physicist. Fourth paragraph: Average Doctor.

Answer (score 6):

No. The interior of the TARDIS occupies a different dimension (it's "dimensionally transcendental"), which is how it packs so much in what to us appears to be a small space.

*If* we suppose that the quote should be taken at face-value (and personally I choose to believe the Doctor was being hyperbolic), then the TARDIS can be infinitely large in terms of space in the realm it's occupying. That doesn't mean it is infinitely large in terms of space in *our* universe/dimension.

Comment: I like the idea of the Doctor being hyperbolic, as opposed to answering "the Doctor lies" all the time to any inconsistency.

Comment: @MrLister: Yeah I thought that line was getting a little old ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a matter of phrasing.

The Doctor probably intended to convey the idea that the TARDIS is "infinitely expandable" but has not actually expanded very far yet.

It's a similar concept to an empty "basement universe". Not much in there, relatively speaking, but effectively infinite room for expansion.

As evidence, the journey to the center of the TARDIS from the outer door only took a few hours. That indicates that it's in the order of a few Kms at most plus the size of the black hole in the center.

As further evidence, he has previously jettisoned individual rooms to balance his energy needs. That would only make sense if the rooms were of significant size compared to the entire TARDIS.

Also bear in mind he is a notorious braggard and unreliable narrator who claims to also have serious memory loss issues.

Answer (score 1):

As an analogy, consider: the TARDIS is infinite, meaning "its size is not finite" or, in (several) other words, the TARDIS can be whatever size it needs to be to contain whatever it is it needs to contain. If something very large must be brought in, the TARDIS will change its size to contain the item. If said item is removed the TARDIS may choose to adjust its size so that it is no longer large enough to contain the item which is no longer there. If the need arises for an infinitely long corridor or an infinitely large room the TARDIS will supply said space - all while still being inside the TARDIS. Perhaps where we're hung up is on the word "infinite". Perhaps a better term would be "recursive flexibility". :-)

Answer (score 0):

Although the TARDIS is described as infinitely large and seemingly similar to a black hole because of its infinite mass inside of a single telephone box, that does not mean that it contains everything similar to the infinite decimal set between 1.1 and 1.2 which is an infinite set yet most definitely, clearly does not contain every number which is also applicable to the Doctor's TARDIS.

Comment: While correct, this doesn't add much to the answers already posted. However, welcome to SFF Stack Exchange! I hope you'll poke around a bit and find something else here that you can answer :-)