# Is the inside of the Tardis bigger than the Universe?

Tags: doctor-who, tardis

The Doctor and some other people make references to the TARDIS being infinite so does that mean the inside of the TARDIS is bigger than the universe itself?

Comment: Duplicate of [How big is the interior of the TARDIS?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7608/how-big-is-the-interior-of-the-tardis)

Comment: @JamesM  I once read that it was possible for there to be different infinites, all infinite, but some larger than others.  At the present time it is unknown whether the universe is incredibly vast but finite or infinite.  Thus it is possible for both the Tardis interior and the universe to be infinite, and for the universe to be larger than the Tardis interior, or the tardis interior larger than the universe.   If the universe is finite, it might be contained inside the Tardis interior somewhere, while at the same time containing the Tardis exterior which contains the Tardis interior.

Comment: Wibbly-wobbly spacey-wacey.